# Toggle Divs Based on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Basically, I need a Points of Interest Key, that would have 8 div buttons, and when each one is clicked, would display info.  Clicking them would toggle them on or off, and more than one can be shown at the same time.  The eighth button when clicked, would show all.  I have a rough idea of code, but I want to use jquery to detect when 8 unique DIVS are click/unclicked, i found this example using input types......

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".red").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".green").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $(".blue").toggle();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

For the toggle all button, i check if all information are displayed, close all of them if true, show all of them otherwise

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Checkboxes</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .btn, .specialBtn{
        width: 35%;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data("toggleid");
        if(id == "0"){
            // toggle all
            var visibleCount = $(".box:visible").length;
            if(visibleCount < 3) $(".box").show();
            else $(".box").hide();
        }
        else{
         $("#info" + id).toggle();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="btn" data-toggleid="1">toggle info 1</div>
        <div class="btn" data-toggleid="2">toggle info 2</div>
        <div class="btn" data-toggleid="3">toggle info 3</div>
        <div class="btn" data-toggleid="0">toggle all</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="info1">info1</div>
    <div class="box" id="info2">info2</div>
    <div class="box" id="info3">info3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are welcome @user1741853! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.For more information, take a look at our FAQ. Thanks and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

not an answer as such, but an observation: - you do not need all those If's... just get the value on the click of the checkbox and use that to directly target the div's toggle(). As follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var clicked=$(this).val();
            $("." + clicked).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, how would I change the var clicked to pickup if a DIV of a certain class name is clicked?

Comment: in the codelab example- the coloured boxes do not have id's so you can use the box class to detect the click...         $('.box').click(function(){
        var clickedBox=$(this).text()
            alert(clickedBox);
    });